# Ruby 2.0 Open Uri always uses proxy, even with proxy = nil flag

Tags: ruby, proxy, ruby-2.0, open-uri

The following call is made in our code base:

```
require 'open-uri'

open(url, :proxy => nil)
```

However, when the call is made, *Open uri* uses the `http_proxy` environment variable to make the call, which is effectively blocked by our firewall. According to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open) when passing `nil` or `false` to the `proxy` option, the environment variables should be ignored as well, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

If we either switch to Ruby version `1.8.7` or `unset` the environment variable, the call is made successfully without the proxy. The problem is that we need to use a proxy for calls to the internet, but we cannot use them for internal calls (which is the case here) due to our firewall configuration.

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce what you described

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1 ruby -e "require 'open-uri'; open('http://google.com', proxy: nil)"
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:313:in `open_http'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:708:in `buffer_open'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:688:in `open'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I've digged the [code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/open-uri.rb), and I think I've found the problem.

So far `open-uri` manage correctly the proxy. For instance, in `OpenURI.open_loop`, it correctly considers that the `proxy` is set to `nil` (see [open-uri.rb#195](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/open-uri.rb#L195)

```
case opt_proxy
when true
  find_proxy = lambda {|u| pxy = u.find_proxy; pxy ? [pxy, nil, nil] : nil}
when nil, false
  find_proxy = lambda {|u| nil} # <-- THIS LINE
```

But when it [creates](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/open-uri.rb#L291) a `Net::HTTP` instance into `OpenURI.open_http`

```
http = klass.new(target_host, target_port)
```

it doesn't pass `p_addr = nil`. According the [source code and doc](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/http.rb#L609) for `HTTP.new`

```
def HTTP.new(address, port = nil, p_addr = :ENV, p_port = nil, p_user = nil, p_pass = nil)
  http = super address, port

  if proxy_class? then # from Net::HTTP::Proxy()
    http.proxy_from_env = @proxy_from_env
    http.proxy_address = @proxy_address
    http.proxy_port = @proxy_port
    http.proxy_user = @proxy_user
    http.proxy_pass = @proxy_pass
  elsif p_addr == :ENV then # <---- THIS LINE
    http.proxy_from_env = true
  else
    http.proxy_address = p_addr
    http.proxy_port = p_port || default_port
    http.proxy_user = p_user
    http.proxy_pass = p_pass
  end

  http
end
```

Above the doc says

> To disable proxy detection set +p_addr+ to nil.

I've patched `open-uri.rb` by replacing the [line 291](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/open-uri.rb#L291) by

```
http = proxy ? klass.new(target_host, target_port) : klass.new(target_host, target_port, nil)
```

Now, it behaves as expected.

---

just filled an [issue in Ruby bug tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9385) about that.

Comment: I haven't really done anything like this before, so how would you go about Monkey Patching this in a project to get it to work (where would the files go, etc.)? Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Nicolay In that case, simply reopen the module won't work, I've tried. I didn't get the time to understand why in that case. What I did, is to directly update the installed `open-uri.rb` to try my patch. But it's definitively not clean. I'd suggest two better options: 1/ use [rvm to run patch](http://rvm.io/rubies/patching) 2/ unset the proxy environment variable in your code and comment it to clearly state it's a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried to reopen the module unsuccessfully. What we ended up doing was to simply remove the `open-uri` dependency and just use `net-http` directly instead. Couldn't have done it without you, cheers!

Comment: @Nicolay good news, it will be fixed in following releases cf https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9385